# Google app engine Channel API for COMET on non Javascript clients

Tags: python, google-app-engine, channel-api

How to use Google app engine [Channel API](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html) for COMET on non JavaScript clients.

I shall be writing a client in python or any other language, and can do HTTP or Socks from client.

How shall I proceed, I want to know what is happening in backed of  JavaScript client?
Is JS using Long Polling or what to talk to GAE server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The asynchronous message passing is done by embedding a hidden iframe in the page, then using the goog.net.CrossPageChannel classes from the Google Closure javascript library to send messages from the iframe to the host page.

The Closure CrosspageChannel code is documented here: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/!svn/bc/4/trunk/closure/goog/docs/class_goog_net_xpc_CrossPageChannel.html

You can easily reverse-engineer the messages that'll be passed up from the iframe to the host page. These probably won't change (though there's no absolute guarantee of that right now).

I'm hoping to open-source the client library for the Channel API this quarter, but the above should get you started.

Comment: @Moishe Does that mean the Javascript client for Channel API is Closure library?

Answer (score 4):

I've reverse-engineered the javascript Channel API client and created a [python library](http://schibum.blogspot.com/2011/06/using-google-appengine-channel-api-with.html).
Feel free to use it. I haven't tested it on any real-world application yet, but from what I can see it seems to work quite well.

Answer (score 3):

Google App Engine has not yet published any documentation about the protocol behind the Channel API so there's no development of libraries outside the Javascript language (here a wrapper for [Gwt](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-channel/)).

If you are interested you could star these feature requests:
[4189 - Enable Java clients (not just javascript) to use the Channel API](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4189)
[4226 - Channel API for native client apps?](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4226)
[4206 - Create a native C# client library for the Channel API](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4206)

Comment: has any body tried to reverse engineer the client side activity at low level.

Comment: could be possible but Afaik no public documentation yet

Answer (score 3):

If you want bi-directional updates from a non-JS client, you can use [XMPP](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp.html).

Answer (score 0):

Cool,... I found an X-Ray view of "channel api" on the app engine talk og Google I/O
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMXe-xK0BWA

It uses hidden Iframe
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)#Hidden_iframe

Now i will try to imitate th client in  python or something.